# problem with getting json data inside ngrx effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I spent the last 2 days with a problem while trying to get a local json data (posts) to show it in the view (PostsComponent).
in the console i get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

but i think its not an object, i'm trying to return it as an array.

and another thing, when i try to log the result it is shown like this: `{ posts: [] }` so it is an object contains an empty array.

i'm inside a module called BaseModule.

here is the shape of the post and the BaseModule state:

```
export interface BaseState {
  posts: Post[];
}

export class Post {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  imageSrc: string;
  author: {name: string, account: string, imageSrc: string};
  date: string;
  categories: string[];
}
```

I created posts.actions.ts file:

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Post } from "src/app/types";

export const getAllPosts = createAction('[PostsComponent] Load Posts');
export const getAllPostsSuccessed = createAction(
  '[[PostsComponent] Load Posts Successed',
  props<{posts: Post[]}>()
);
export const getAllPostsError = createAction(
  '[PostsComponent] Load Posts Error',
  props<{error: any}>()
);
```

then the posts.reducer.ts file:

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import * as postsActions from "./posts.actions";
import { BaseState } from "src/app/types";

const initialState: BaseState = {
  posts: []
}

const _postsReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(postsActions.getAllPosts, state => state),
  on(postsActions.getAllPostsSuccessed, (state, { posts }) => {
    console.log(posts); return {...state, posts: posts};
  }),
  on(postsActions.getAllPostsError, (state, { error }) => { console.log(error); return state})
);

export function postsReducer(state: any, action: any){
  return _postsReducer(state, action);
}
```

and the posts.selectors.ts file:

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";
import { BaseState } from "src/app/types";

const selectBase = createFeatureSelector<BaseState>('base');

export const posts = createSelector(
  selectBase,
  (state: BaseState) => state.posts
);
```

then finally the posts.effects.ts file:

```
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError, map, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Post } from "src/app/types";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { of } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class PostsEffects {

  getPosts = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
    ofType('[PostsComponent] Load Posts'),
    mergeMap(() => this.http.get<{posts: Post[]}>('assets/posts.json').pipe(
      map(posts => ({type: '[PostsComponent] Load Posts Successed', posts: posts})),
      catchError(error => of({type: '[PostsComponent] Load Posts Error', error: error}))
    ))
  ));

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private actions: Actions
  ) { }

}
```

and this is the posts.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { BaseState, Post } from "src/app/types";
import { getAllPosts } from "./state/posts.actions";
import { posts } from "./state/posts.selector";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.scss']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: Post[];
  limit = 6;

  constructor(private store: Store<BaseState>) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(getAllPosts());
    this.store.select(posts).subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
    console.log(this.posts);
  }

  get getPosts(){
    return this.posts;
  }

  showMore(){
    this.limit = this.limit + 6;
  }

}
```

and the posts.component.html file:

```
<div class="post" *ngFor="let post of getPosts">
  <div class="title"><a [routerLink]="'/post/' + post.id.toString()">{{ post.title }}</a></div>
  <div class="content">
    {{ post.content | slice:0:30 }}<a [routerLink]="'/post/' + post.id.toString()">...Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img [src]="post.imageSrc">
  </div>
  <div class="author" routerLink="#">
    <img [src]="post.author.imageSrc">
    {{ post.author.name }}
  </div>
  <div class="date">{{ post.date }}</div>
  <div class="categories">
    <div class="category" *ngFor="let category of post.categories">
      {{ category }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="show-more" (click)="showMore()">Show More</div>
```

i'm new to angular and ngrx so please make the answers clear for a beginner.

Comment: Are you using ngrx because you're working on an existing project, or because you want to/have been told to/another reason? I strongly recommend not using ngrx within Angular apps because it's just not needed and *massively* overcomplicates and confuses the code-base and developers alike. It's not a simple or nice thing to use and is almost completely irrelevant in an Angular app (do some reading on the origins and usages of the store pattern, and ultimately it's irrelevant for Angular due to its DI system and singleton services, subscriptions, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here were the problem was:

first:

there was a character "[" added by mistake in the actions file:
`'[[PostsComponent] Load Posts Successed'`

second:

the json data was made in a wrong type like: `{posts: [...]}`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason for using ngrx, I suggest dumping it and using standard services. The minor amount of implementation you may have to do around things is by far much less and easier than trying to do even the most basic things with ngrx.

E.g. Your question has 7 sections of code to do a simple post retrieval.
Here's a simplified version of events, using basic, built-in features.

Component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subs: Subscription[];

  private _posts: Post[];

  constructor(private readonly service: PostService) {
    this.subs = [];
  }

  public get posts(): Post[] { return this._posts; }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subs.push(this.service.posts$
      .subscribe((x: Post[]) => this.onPostsResponse(x)));

    this.service.getPosts();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subs.forEach((x: Subscription) => x.unsubscribe());
  }

  private onPostsResponse(posts: Post[]): void {
    this._posts = posts;
  }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  private posts: Post[];

  private postsObs: Observer<Post[]>;

  private _posts$: Observable<Post[]>;

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
    this._posts$ = new Observable<Post[]>((x: Observable<Post[]>) => {this.postsObs = x;}).pipe(share());
  }

  public get posts$(): Observable<Post[]> { return this._posts$; }

  public getPosts(): void {
    const sub = this.http.get('.../posts')
      .subscribe((response: Post[]) => {
        sub.unsubscribe();
        this.posts = response;
        this.emitPosts();
      });
  }

  private emitPosts(): void {
    if (this.postsObs) this.postsObs.next(this.posts);
  }
}
```

That's it, minus whatever other features you want it to have. I'm saving post response directly to the `this.posts` variable, but I'm not actually using it, just overwriting it every time.

I see you have a show more: that's easily extended such that you wrap up your getPosts method so that it returns from the variable as much as it's able. Once 'more' posts are requested that exceed the number of posts you have cached, you can then make the actual API request and *add* to the posts rather than straight overwrite them, and return the new set.

If you keep your post requests a page or two ahead of anything the use can do, the user won't have any load times either. They'll be immediately receiving their next page of posts whilst you fetch the next page(s) in the background.

Until you have an API in place, you can return whatever dummy data you want (and even slap it in a `setTimeout` to simulate a second or two of loading time):

```
  public getPosts(): void {
    this.posts = dummyData;

    setTimeout(() => {this.emitPosts();}, 2000}; // 2s delay

    //const sub = this.http.get('.../posts')
    //  .subscribe((response: Post[]) => {
    //    sub.unsubscribe();
    //    this.posts = response;
    //    this.emitPosts();
    //  });
  }

  private dummyData: Post[] = [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
  ];
```

Now you have a service which you can have your app module provide (and thus be an app-wide singleton), that is fetching, storing, and emitting Posts that any component can subscribe to and receive data whenever something (or itself) calls getPosts - just like the store pattern and essentially what ngrx does, but without all those effects and reducers and awful complexity.

Comment: I understand that i could do it with fewer steps. but the idea is that I'm trying to convert an old project to a new one and use ngrx just for learning. I did the old project just as you said (getting data by services) and it was working cool. so.. the idea is this project is going to be big and complicated and that's why I'm using ngrx for. sorry for the late response.

Comment: If you deliberately want to go the more complex ngrx route, then my answer is of no help and I can't directly help you with ngrx implementation. Just remember that big projects don't have to be complicated - KISS is one of the devs main acronyms for a reason. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is the first time i read about the KISS principle. I solved the problem today with help of my teacher. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Krenom this is opinion based and doesn't answer the question. `ngrx store` is perfectly valid for angular projects as is a service based solution.

Comment: @SWilko Indeed, this is why I clearly stated that my answer is of no help and wished him luck.